# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.text.WordUtils

Tags: java, apache

I can't figure out why I'm getting a ClassNotFoundException here, since I have compiled with the appropriate jar file for WorkUtils, and the class WordUtils is clearly in the jar file.

I compiled with `javac -d bin -cp lib/commons-text-1.2.jar MyClass.java`
and run with `java -cp bin MyClass`

Here is my java class:

```
import org.apache.commons.text.WordUtils;

class MyClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(WordUtils.capitalize("sample text"));

    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/text/WordUtils
    at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.text.WordUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Anyone know what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The library must also be sent to `java`:

```
java -cp bin:lib/commons-text-1.2.jar MyClass
```

If you're on Windows, you may need to replace `:` with `;`

Comment: I am also facing the same issue with `org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils`. I added it to my dynamic web project's class path (I am on eclipse). Any idea how to do the above on eclipse?

Comment: @Miraj50 If the jar is added to the web project and you can see it in `<webapp>/web-inf/lib`, then it should work. You can check your deployment assembly to see if it's included.

Comment: I manually checked `web-inf/lib` and didn't find it there. I am guessing the way to add a jar file is different for a dynamic web project than for a application client project. What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: @Miraj50 Are you using any build tool such as maven/gradle?

Comment: No, I am not using any build tool. My project is simple. It just uses tomcat to show what I am doing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178448/discussion-between-miraj50-and-ernest-k).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using commons-text 1.4+, you have to use Java 8. Make sure you're using the right version of Java; That was the cause of my `NoClassDefFoundError`.