# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils

Tags: java, gradle, stringescapeutils, apache-commons-text

I am trying to call a method, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils
```

From what I understood I was supposed to have this dependency in my `build.gradle` file:

```
dependecies {
    ...

    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-text', version: '1.6'
    ...
}
```

I  did that, but I keep getting the abovementioned error. I also tried the `v1.9` of `org.apache.commons-commons-text` dependency as well, again with the same results.

Is there something else I am missing?

I also tried to do what was answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138525/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-commons-text-wordutils) question but it does not seem to work.

Comment: The answer you linked to is about `ClassNotFoundException`. That is not the same as [NoClassDefFoundError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html). Your code compiles because Apache Commons is in your build path but your code fails at runtime because the runtime class path (or module path) does not include Apache Commons. I don't know [gradle](https://gradle.org/) so I can't tell you how to fix it.

Comment: Do you know how to make it work in  another type of project (e.g. maven)? maybe this would help

Comment: Don't use Maven either. Refer to the [java command documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE)

Comment: I saw this error with apktool, version 2.7.0